# How to implement EF 3.0 LCIA method in Brightway2?

Tags: brightway

For a project I need to use LCIA method EF 3.0. The JRC has provided all sort of files: https://eplca.jrc.ec.europa.eu/LCDN/developerEF.xhtml.
However I don't have any clue how I could implement this in bw2, as I'm just starting to use bw2. Does someone have experience in implementing EF 3.0 in bw2 who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing EF 3.0 is basically impossible for someone who is just starting, as you need to have strong knowledge of the whole Brightway stack, as well as LCA, including its unstated assumptions and common metadata. However, you aren't the only one working on this, so we will take it up in the developer's circle, and try to get a method implemented by June 2021.

Comment: OK, thanks for your response Chris! It would be great if it would be possible to implement EF 3.0 soon. It would solve my issue.